# Targeting specific versions of Internet Explorer in PHP

Tags: php, internet-explorer, conditional-statements

I am using the following PHP to target all browsers except Internet Explorer:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'MSIE') == false)) {
   DO STUFF
   }
```

I now want to target specific versions of Internet Explorer, i.e. to exclude only IE8 and lower versions, as opposed to all versions of IE.

How would I adapt the code above to achieve this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function ie($version) {

if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $version) !== false)
{ return true; }
return false;

}   

if (ie('MSIE 8.') == true || ie('MSIE 7.') == true || ie('MSIE 6.') == true) { 
echo "Do something";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks like this is just targeting IE8. Is there a way of targeting IE7 and IE6 in the same statement?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should look at [get_browser](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
```

You can also do

```
$ie8 = (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE 8.') !== FALSE);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I am using `if($browser->browser = 'IE' && $browser->majorver <= 8) {} else { DO STUFF }` but it's not working - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: mmmh, it appears that I need to install browscap.  I don't have access to my php.ini, so will have to check with the host about this

Comment: How would I then use $ie8 in your second example?  I have tried `if (!isset($ie8)) { DO STUFF }`, but this isn't working

Answer (score 1):

this function return the ie version

```
function detectIEversion() {
      ereg('MSIE ([0-9].[0-9])',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],$reg);
      if(!isset($reg[1])) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return floatval($reg[1]);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Using a deprecated function like ereg isn't good practise when answering a question